# Подключение к Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, proxy

У меня интернет через прокси с авторизацией. Никак не могу подключиться к бд Postgresql на удаленном сервере по ip.
При этом подключался через прямой интернет все работает хорошо. Как подключиться через прокси?

Comment: Если хотите подключиться к своему серверу через прокси, который используется в браузере, то практически никак. Хотя вроде есть вроде варианты. Или под прокси подразумевается что-то другое? Откуда пошло такое желание непременно прокси? Если надо защитить postgres от прямого подключения из интернет, то можно построить ssh-туннель. Так в основном и поступают. Методика хорошо описана. Если например с работы не дают подключаться куда попало, то это другое дело. Попробуйте договориться с админом.

Answer (score 0):

Padmin III умеет подключатся к postgress через прокси.